# Calling toast.show function in Unit Testing in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, toast, android-toast

I wish to test out my Alert toast class inside Unit Testing. However, when I call `alert_toast.show`, I get an error `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`.

I understand that I cant call UI related elements such as Toast from worker class or other processing class, such as Unit Testings. However, is there a way I can call `alert_toast.show` inside my Unit Testings?

My alert_toast class code

```
public class Custom_toasts {
    private Context context;
    private final int TOAST_TEXT_COLOR = R.color.white;
    private final int TOAST_TEXT_GRAVITY = Gravity.CENTER;
    private boolean toast_shown = false;
    private Toast toast;

    public Custom_toasts(Context context){
        this.context = context;

    }
    public Toast getToast(){
        return toast;
    }
    public void show_toast(String message,int toast_color){
        toast_shown = false;

        toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        View view = toast.getView();

        //Gets the actual oval background of the Toast then sets the colour filter
        int background_color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, toast_color);
        view.getBackground().setColorFilter((background_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        //Gets the TextView from the Toast so it can be editted
        TextView text = view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);

        int string_color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, TOAST_TEXT_COLOR);
        text.setTextColor((string_color));
        text.setGravity(TOAST_TEXT_GRAVITY);

        toast.show();
        toast_shown = true;
    }
    public boolean getToast_shown(){
        return toast_shown;
    }

}
```

I've done a little research, and most answers show that I can show toast, but only if the toast is shown **after** I've clicked on a button on the UI, say clicking on a button will show a toast. As seen here: (https://gist.github.com/brunodles/badaa6de2ad3a84138d517795f15efc7).

I don't want to create another layout.xml just to test this toast will show when alert_toast.show is called.